# Facebook feed dialog not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-feed

I am trying to get the Facebook Feed dialog to work at a test site but I keep getting the same error message: "An error occurred with [app_name]. Please try again later.". 
When I look at the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) I realize that the example in the documentation doesn't work either.

Have tried a number of different solutions.
Here is my test code:

```
 <html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '400714233333865', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      channelUrl : '//demo.xxxxxxx.se/nptest/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

  };

  function postToFeed(){

  FB.ui(
  {
   method: 'feed',
   name: 'The Facebook SDK for Javascript',
   caption: 'Bringing Facebook to the desktop and mobile web',
   description: (
      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
   ),
   link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/',
   picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);

};

  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>



     <div id='fb-root'></div>
<a onClick="postToFeed('Text');">
    Share in the feeeeeeeeeeeeed
</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Has anyone come across a similar issue or a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are testing through same URL as specified in Application settings. In your feed dialog give your own links and images i.e. links of your own domain specified in Application setting and not one given in Facebook example.

Comment: That's it! Can't believe that I have missed that all day. Thanks man!